# How to updata a pandas dataframe with column and index numbers from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, merge

I have a reference dataframe df1 with 7 columns and 7 rows. The columns and indices are both 0-7. All values are 0. (That is being said, I have a 7x7 dataframe of 49 0s.)

I have another smaller dataframe df2 with n columns and n rows, where n is a random number <=7. The columns and indices are n numbers in the range of [0, 7]. The values are random values.

You can see the examples below.

What I want to do is replace the 0s in df1 where df2 has the same index+column, and keep the 0s in df1 where there is no match in df2.

**This is df1**

```
# create a 7*7 dataframe of 0s
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((7, 7)))
print(df1.columns)
print(df1.index)
df1
```

[image]

**This is df2**

```
# create random n-dimention-dataframe, where n must <= 6
import random
n = random.randrange(1, 7) 
arr = np.random.randint(500, size=(n, n))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index = random.sample(range(0, 7), n), columns = random.sample(range(0, 7), n))
print(df2.columns)
print(df2.index)
df2
```

[image]

So, eventually, I want something like this. I made this example table in excel because that's why I'm here - I want a dataframe like this - the index and column are the same and in the same order as df1; some values come from df2; unmatched cells remain 0. A reminder that it needs to be **automated to detect what column/index numbers are in df2** to make the replacement, as df2 comes from random generators.
[image]

Thanks a lot if you could please help!!

Comment: `df1.loc[df2.index, df2.columns] = df2.loc[df2.index, df2.columns]`

Comment: Seems like you could just [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df2` directly without `df1` being pre-created -> `df1 = df2.reindex(index=range(7), columns=range(7), fill_value=0)` unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks, d.b and @Henry Ecker. Both methods work. :)

Comment: //Thanks, @d.b and Henry Ecker. Both methods work. :)